# Content of assets (images, js and css) switches randomly on different requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app - cloudlist (cloudli.st) - uses Heroku, rails 3.2 and a bunch of gems. For the past few days we've started seeing our layout break a few hours after a deploy.

The strange thing is that the content of a file switches randomly on different requests. We use the rails asset pipeline with all defaults, nothing changed. Right after the deploy everything is fine. After some time (usually a couple of hours) the layouts starts to break in some areas. Sometimes just one image has a different content, sometimes even JS or CSS files have different content. We've also seen files that were completely mixed up. All this is very strange and I can't find anything on the web.

To illustrate the problem see the following image which have sprites with the wrong content.

[image]

Also see the content of the file frame.png. It should show the frame for a tile but sometimes it shows the awards nominee badge.

[image]

**Has anyone seen anything similar or do you know how to solve this?**

If this continues we need to migrate away from Heroku and use another infrastructure.

Comment: Trying to debug the problem is pretty hard. Actually it's just playing around with parameters / configs, deploying and waiting if the site still brakes.

What I did so far is deactivating digest for assets and trying to precompile the assets. In the first place precompiling seemed to be the problem-solver but this morning the site was again broken.

Comment: turning off rails caching (config.action_controller.perform_caching = false) in my production settings makes the site work again. So I conclude this is a caching problem which has to be investigated by heroku staff.

Comment: Did you ask Heroku help about caching? If that's the correct answer you should answer your own question and [accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/189918) :)  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I asked heroku for help but what I got was a link to the faq. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31

Maybe this solves 99% of all tickets related to caching but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the recommendation given by heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31) here are the results.

**In short:** it didn't help.

**Long version:**

I don't use memcached for caching. Neither I use fragment or action caching. At least I don't use caching at all in my app.

The only thing that gets cached is stuff done by the configuration parameter

**config.action_controller.perform_caching = false**

in production environment.

I went through the article and checked every parameter. The only one I had different was **config.serve_static_assets** which was **false**. I set this to true, redeployed (with caching turned on) and got the same issues after a couple of hours.

I don't know what's wrong but as there is content in my files which doesn't match the expected I have to conclude that this is something within your infrastructure. E.g. I request **application-(any-digest).css** and I get **sprite-(any-digest).png** or **application-(any-digest).js**